# How to get unique values in a column, including cells with multiple values seperated by commas, in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a column in a Google Sheet, which in some cases, includes multiple values separated by commas — like this:

| Value |
| --- |
| A example |
| B example |
| C example |
| D example |
| A example, E example |
| A example, F example |
| G example, D example, C example |

I would like to count all occurrences of the unique values in this column, so the count should look like:

| Unique value | Occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| A example | 3 |
| B example | 1 |
| C example | 2 |
| D example | 2 |
| E example | 1 |
| F example | 1 |
| G example | 1 |

Currently, however, when I use =UNIQUE(A2:A), the result gives this:

| Unique value | Occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| A example | 1 |
| B example | 1 |
| C example | 1 |
| D example | 1 |
| A example, E example | 1 |
| A example, F example | 1 |
| G example, D example, C example | 1 |

Is there a way I can count all of the instances of letters, whether they appear in individually in a cell or appear alongside other letters in a cell (comma-seperated)?

(This looks like a useful answer [in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260714/counting-unique-values-in-a-column), but I'm trying to do this in Google Sheets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1:A,", ")),""),"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''"))
```

Or, as per the comments, split on the combination instead:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1:A,", ",0)),""),"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''"))
```

---

2nd EDIT: To order descending by count use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1:A,", ",0)),""),"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 Order By count(Col1) desc label count(Col1) ''"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  It almost works — I just slightly miscommunicated the context in my original post.  Some of the values in my data actually have spaces within them.  So a cell can include "Value 1, Value 2" — which should be parsed as "Value 1" and "Value 2".  This code parses it into "Value", "1", "2" — again, based on my miscommunication in the original post.  I've updated the post to clarify that the comma seperated values often have spaces in them.  Do you know how to adjust your C1 formula to make that work?

Comment: @amatur, not a problem. Use the third parameter in the `SPLIT()` function to false to avoid splitting on all character but a comma space instead.

Comment: That did it @JvdV, thank you so much again!!  Enjoy a cold one on me!!

Comment: @amatur, received! Since it's high summer I will make sure to enjoy =)

Comment: One more question on this @JvdV.  Is there a way to edit the formula in C1, so column D will be ordered from greatest to least?  So A (3), C (2), D (2), B (1), E (1), F (1), G (1)

Comment: @amatur, It's a simple fix in the query itself to order by count. See edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data in `A1:A7`:

In `C1`:

`=SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A1:A7,", ")))))`

In `D1`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(0+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&ColumnCSpilledRange&", ",", "&TRANSPOSE(A1:A7)&", ")),ROW(A1:A7)^0))`

Replace *ColumnCSpilledRange* appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  It almost works — I just slightly miscommunicated the context in my original post.  Some of the values in my data actually have spaces within them.  So a cell can include "Value 1, Value 2" — which should be parsed as "Value 1" and "Value 2".  This code parses it into "Value", "1", "2" — again, based on my miscommunication in the original post.  I've updated the post to clarify that the comma separated values often have spaces in them.  Do you know how to adjust your C1 formula to make that work?